# AfxGetApp()->m_lpCmdLine for QT?

Tags: c++, qt, mfc

I have an MFC application which makes the use of following code
 `AfxGetApp()->m_lpCmdLine`  .
 Being novice in MFC I learned that `AfxGetApp()->m_lpCmdLine` points to a null terminated string that specifies the command line for the application .

Now IF I want to do the same in Qt how would  I do  it ?

I know to get the APP name I  Can use `QFileInfo(QApplication::applicationFilePath()).fileName()`similar to AFxGetApp but  how would I get commands from cmdline ?
Using 5.1 Qt.
platform Windows7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [QCoreApplication::arguments()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#arguments). You get a `QStringList`.